# Generating PMML in WEKA

Tags: weka, pmml

Can someone tell me how to download “WekaScoring” pluggin to WEKA? the link so far I could find was 
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/List+of+Available+Pentaho+Data+Integration+Plug-In but this is not accessible.

What I need is I need to generate a PMML model for WEKA. Is it possible in WEKA?

Answer (score 0):

What are the current limitations of Weka's PMML support?

Only PMML Regression, GeneralRegression, NeuralNetwork, TreeModel, RuleSetModel and SupportVectorMachineModel are implemented so far. GeneralRegression supports a single Predictor-to-Parameter matrix (i.e. in the case of classification, each target class value shares the same PPMatrix). Aggregate and MapValues expressions are not supported yet. The first six of the eleven PMML built-in functions are supported so far. There is no support for exporting PMML models from Weka yet.

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/PMML+Support+in+Weka